# Conditional Rendering in Vue JS for Firebase isLoggedin State?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

**How to Implement Conditional Rendering in Vue JS for Firebase isLoggedIn State**
I want to show a Element (example: Button) that Only Shows in Navbar, When Firebase State isLoggedIn True!
Framework Configs: VueJS with Firebase, Tailwind, DaisyUI, HyperUI.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've Tried Computed Property but then Everything Hides,

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - I'm Trying to Do When User is Already Logged in then Hide the Register Option and Show Profile Avatar and Vice Versa in Navbar Component.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim currently deleted that code, looking forward for new. using v-if="loggedin == true" but my code didn't changing boolean value.